# How to export multiple variable in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to use **izitoast.d.ts** file from [IziToast](https://github.com/dolce/iziToast) plugin.

```
// Type definitions for IziToast
// Project https://github.com/dolce/iziToast
// Definitions by: Tarık İNCE <incetarik@hotmail.com> and Marcelo Dolce <dolcemarcelo@gmail.com>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped 

type IziToastPosition = "bottomRight" | "bottomLeft" | "topRight" | "topLeft" | "topCenter" | "bottomCenter" | "center"
type IziToastTransitionIn = "bounceInLeft" | "bounceInRight" | "bounceInUp" | "bounceInDown" | "fadeIn" | "fadeInDown" | "fadeInUp" | "fadeInLeft" | "fadeInRight" | "flipInX"
type IziToastTransitionOut = "fadeOut" | "fadeOutUp" | "fadeOutDown" | "fadeOutLeft" | "fadeOutRight" | "flipOutX"

interface IziToastSettings {
    /**
     * Id of the toast
     */
    id?: string,
    /**
     * The class that will be applied to the toast. It may be used as a reference.
     */
    class?: string,
    /** 
     * Title of the toast.
     */
    title?: string,
    /** 
     * Title color. 
     */
    titleColor?: string,
    /** 
     * Title fontSize. 
     */
    titleSize?: string,
    /** 
     * Title lineHeight. 
     */
    titleLineHeight?: string,
    /** 
     * Message of notification. 
     */
    message: string,
    /** 
     * Message color. 
     */
    messageColor?: string,
    /** 
     * Message fontSize. 
     */
    messageSize?: string,
    /** 
     * Message lineHeight. 
     */
    messageLineHeight?: string,
    /** 
     * Background color of the Toast 
     */
    backgroundColor?: string,
    /** 
     * It can be #hexadecimal, pre-defined themes like blue, red, green and yellow or set another class. Create and use like this ".iziToast-color-name" 
     */
    color?: string, 
    /** 
     * Icon class (font-icon of your choice, Icomoon, Fontawesome etc.). 
     */
    icon?: string,
    /** 
     * Icon text (font-icon using text, Material Icons, etc.). 
     */
    iconText?: string,
    /** 
     * Icon color. 
     */
    iconColor?: string,
    /** 
     * Cover image. 
     */
    image?: string,
    /**
     * Width of cover image. 
     * Example 100(px)
     * Default value: null
     */
    imageWidth?: number | null,
    /**
     * Sets maxWidth of toast. 
     * Example 500px 
     * Default value: null
     */
    maxWidth?: number | null,
    /** 
     * The z-index CSS attribute of the toast
     * Default value: null
     */
    zindex?: number | null,
    /** 
     * It can be 1 or 2, or use another layout, creating the class like this: ".iziToast-layout3" 
     * Default value: 1
     */
    layout?: number,
    /**
     * Applies a balloon like toast. 
     * Default value: false
    */
    balloon?: boolean,
    /**
     * Show "x" close button.
     * Default value: true
     */
    close?: boolean,
    /**
     * RTL option
     * Default value: false
     */
    rtl?: boolean,
    /**
     * Where it will be shown. 
     * Default value: bottomRight
     */
    position?: IziToastPosition 
    /** Fixed place where you want to show the toasts. */
    target?: string,
    /** 
     * Add toast to first position. 
     * Default value: true
     */
    targetFirst?: boolean,
    /**
     * Waits for another toast to be closed on 'onClosed' function. You'll need an ID to use it.
     */
    toastOnce?: boolean,
    /** 
     * Amount in milliseconds to close the toast or false to disable. 
     * Default value: 5000
     */
    timeout?: boolean | number,
    /**
     * Drag feature used to close the toast.
     * Default value: true 
     */
    drag?: boolean,
    /** 
     * Pause the toast timeout while the cursor is on it. 
     * Default value: true
     */
    pauseOnHover?: boolean,
    /**
     * Reset the toast timeout while the cursor is on it. 
     * Default value: false
     */
    resetOnHover?: boolean,
    /** 
     * Enable timeout progress bar. 
     * Default value: true
     */
    progressBar?: boolean,
    /** 
     * Progress bar color. 
     */
    progressBarColor?: string,
    /**
     * Enable animations of elements in the toast.
     * Default value: true
     */
    animateInside?: boolean,
    /** 
     * Array of buttons.
     * Array is an array of array that contains (string, function (instance, toast)) types.
     */
    buttons?: ([string, (instance: IziToast, toast: HTMLDivElement) => void])[],
    /**
     * Default toast open animation.
     * Default value: 'fadeInUp'
     */
    transitionIn?: IziToastTransitionIn,
    /**
     * Default toast close animation. 
     * Default value: 'fadeOut'
     */
    transitionOut?: IziToastTransitionOut,
    /**
     * Default toast opening mobile transition. 
     * Default value: 'fadeInUp'
     */
    transitionInMobile?: IziToastTransitionIn,
    /**
     * Default toast closing mobile transition. 
     * Default value: 'fadeOutDown'
     */
    transitionOutMobile?: IziToastTransitionOut,
    /** 
     * Callback function triggered when opening the toast. 
     * @param settings Settings of opening toast.
     * @param toast Toast DOM element.
     */
    onOpening?: (settings: IziToastSettings, toast: HTMLDivElement) => void,
    /** 
     * Callback function triggered when opened the toast. 
     * @param settings Settings of opening toast.
     * @param toast Toast DOM element.
     */
    onOpened?: (settings: IziToastSettings, toast: HTMLDivElement) => void,
    /** 
     * Callback function triggered when closing the toast. 
     * @param settings Settings of closing toast.
     * @param toast Toast DOM element.
     * @param closedBy Closed by info set by hide method.
     */
    onClosing?: (settings: IziToastSettings, toast: HTMLDivElement, closedBy: string) => void,
    /** 
     * Callback function triggered when closed the toast. 
     * @param settings Settings of closing toast.
     * @param toast Toast DOM element.
     * @param closedBy Closed by info set by hide method.
     */
    onClosed?: (settings: IziToastSettings, toast: HTMLDivElement, closedBy: string) => void,

}

interface IziToast {
    /**
     * Opens the toast. 
     */
    show(settings: IziToastSettings): void
    /**
     * Closes the specific toast.
     * @param settings Settings for this toast.
     * @param toast Toast element to hide.
     * @param closedBy Custom closed by info to use in other functions.
     */
    hide(settings: IziToastSettings, toast: HTMLDivElement, closedBy: string): void
    /**
     * Shows an info toast.
     * @param settings Settings for this toast.
     */
    info(settings: IziToastSettings): void
    /**
     * Shows an error toast.
     * @param settings Settings for this toast.
     */
    error(settings: IziToastSettings): void
    /**
     * Shows a warning toast.
     * @param settings Settings for this toast.
     */
    warning(settings: IziToastSettings): void
    /**
     * Shows a success toast.
     * @param settings Settings for this toast.
     */
    success(settings: IziToastSettings): void

    /**
     * Destroys all toasts.
     */
    destroy(): void

    /**
     * Sets default values.
     * @param settings Settings to set as default.
     */
    settings(settings: IziToastSettings): void;
}

declare var iziToast: IziToast
```

I need to access and create variable from both interfaces IziToastSettings and IziToast

I am not sure what should I do ?! I checked toastr.d.ts and added the code below in above izitoast.d.ts.

```
declare module "iziToast" {
    export = iziToast;
}
```

[image: izi]

and it works in typescript with this way
`import * as izi from 'iziToast';`

but I need more I want to use it in this way

`import { IziToast, IziToastSettings } from 'iziToast';`

I need the access to **both** interfaces specially IziToastSettings but in first way I can use IziToast functionality only.

[image: izi]

How to export multiple variables in Typescript for accessing both interfaces ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`package.json`](https://github.com/dolce/iziToast/blob/master/package.json) of [iziToast](https://github.com/dolce/iziToast/blob/master/package.json) is missing a `typings` entry to specify where the type definitions are.

With this entry, type definitions will automatically be available to the Typescript compiler when you import iziToast.

You should contact the developper but in the meantime, try adding

```
"typings": "dist/izitoast/izitoast.d.ts",
```

to the package.json file of the iziToast module.

Comment: You means the main .d.ts is correct ? I  know about @ types I added local folder in @ types and changed the file name to index.d.ts my problem is about export both interfaces not @ types can you clarify this for me ?

Comment: The .d.ts provided as part of the package is correct. This is how they should be written (as ambient module declarations, not external module declarations). However they need to be declared in the package.json to be picked up by the typescript compiler. You do not need to include it anywhere else

Comment: How can I change it to export based for exporting  IziToast, IziToastSettings? I added it to package.json but I can not use it ! please guide me.

Comment: You added it to the package.json of the **iziToast module** inside your mode_modules ?

Comment: How can I call the variable, interfaces ?

Comment: I have error, import * as izi from 'iziToast'; is not a module

Comment: The module name is `izitoast` not `iziToast`, check the package.json name

Comment: import * as izi from 'izitoast';       izitoast.d.ts' is not a module.   error is the same